# Circular overflow icon for Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to get the 3-circles overflow icon (instead of default 3 little squares overflow icon) in the Android ActionBar? 
Examples - Google+ app, Twitter app

Comment: how about using your custom circles by adding it to the drawable?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2778684

Answer (score 1):

You should always make your own files, or use free ones instead. Closed source apps often don't permit you to use their images files.

When the app's images are open source,it should be safe to extract the APK of the app, and get it by youself. It's just like any Zip file.

In order to get the APK file of the app, you can use my app (available [**here**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager), just choose "share" on the selected app) or any other app that can copy APK files from installed apps . It doesn't even need root for this operation.

It might be a bit different with Google, as they are probably more forgiving for such things, but it's best to not take the risk.